# How do I use the glmer function properly with my data in R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

I have a set of around 23k rows of data. It is a set of animal movement lengths (dist), going from 0 to several thousand, with the majority being around 50 to 100. The data doesn't have a normal distribution. It is considerably skewed to the <s>left</s> right (skeweness = 2.6348, kurtosis = 10.6348). As I understand it, a gamma distribution would be a good fit for my data. I added 0.001 to some 50 or so rows that were 0 because gamma doesn't work with 0's. Picked sex, daytime, season, and status (single or mated) as fixed variables and animal id as random. Then I ran this code in the **lme4** package:

```
model <- glmer(dist ~ sex + daytime + season + (1 | id), 
               data = movement, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
```

The model did converge, and I know how to read the results. But I don't know how to know whether I implemented it well, whether my model is good, or if I have picked the right distribution.

These are my results:

```
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: Gamma  ( log )
Formula: dist ~ status + sex + daytime + season + (1 | id)
   Data: movement

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 328608.2  328680.9 -164295.1  328590.2     23834 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.6880 -0.6320 -0.3674  0.2304 16.1399 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.07636  0.2763  
 Residual             2.11282  1.4536  
Number of obs: 23843, groups:  id, 14

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    5.53540    0.11796  46.928  < 2e-16 ***
statussingle   0.03115    0.12745   0.244 0.806903    
sexfemale     -0.39872    0.10596  -3.763 0.000168 ***
daytimenight   1.18677    0.01833  64.750  < 2e-16 ***
seasonsummer   0.07423    0.02617   2.836 0.004566 ** 
seasonspring   0.01108    0.02731   0.406 0.684841    
seasonwinter   0.11629    0.02838   4.098 4.16e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) sttssn sexfml dytmngh sesnsmr ssnspr
statussingl  -0.766                                   
sexfemale    -0.303 -0.163                            
daytimenight -0.086  0.002  0.004                     
seasonsummer -0.126 -0.004  0.010  0.009              
seasonspring -0.105 -0.039  0.031 -0.043  0.564       
seasonwinter -0.126 -0.030  0.051  0.085  0.514  0.564
```

I suspect there isn't a short answer, and I know I shouldn't be attempting to use the method without understanding it fully. However, I suspect this might be the easiest way to answer the questions I am asking in my research, so I figured I could try it.

Edit: I would like to add that I am fine with having a lot of variance within my data unaccounted for. In fact, I am expecting it. I expect my overall data to be quite chaotic, but I would like to learn if any environmental variables have an influence, even if they are negligible compared to the overall sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your data looks like, but gamma distributions are technically *skewed to the right*, so I'm not sure if that matters in your case since you mentioned it was skewed to the left. At first glance, your regression does not appear inherently "wrong", but that's also assuming your distribution matches something like this:

[image]

Your model only accounts for one specific random effects structure: the random intercepts of individual animals. This isn't an issue per se, though given you are dealing with animals, you may consider other hierarchical random effects that are nested within each other. Variables I'm thinking of are habitats of each animal or the species of the animal if there are enough (more than 5 clusters).

For testing if your mixed model is doing the right thing, there are several checks you should include. First off, I highly recommend reading through [Meteyard & Davies, 2020](https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0749596X20300061), which provides a best practice guide for what to include in your model. For example, they recommend fitting a random-effects only model first to test if a GLMM is even appropriate, which often isn't something I see done in GLMM studies (but should be).

Probably the most overlooked aspect of GLMMs is testing model performance. I would check out the [DHARMA package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html), which performs many useful residual tests for GLMMs. You may also consider some of the features of the [performance package](https://easystats.github.io/performance/), though some functions are only suitable for Gaussian models. It would be useful for checking for things like multicollinearity, pseudo R2, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  As you said, my data is skewed to the right. I misunderstood the term. I am not sure I understood your second paragraph. What would be some examples of hierarchical random effects that are nested within each other? I will look into the materials you provided. Thank you again!

Comment: This paper has some domain-specific examples that may be more accessible to your knowledge base: https://peerj.com/articles/4794

Comment: And this paper explains how to code them (specifically Page 7): http://www.jstatsoft.org/v67/i01/